# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recepient'

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-mail

I got an error while sending mail from my blog to recipients but it throws an error.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.form.get ('name')
    email = request.form.get('email')
    phone = request.form.get('phone')
    message = request.form.get('message')

    entry = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone_no=phone, \
                    date=datetime.now(), message=message)
    db.session.add(entry)
    db.session.commit()
    mail.send_message('A message from Blog' + name,
                      sender=email,
                      recepients=params['gail-user'],
                      body=message + "/n" + phone
                      )

    return render_template('contact.html',params=params)
```

Comment: Not sure. Your error flags: keyword argument 'recepient', but in this piece of code I see recepients, with 's' at the end. Maybe it expects to receive recepients as parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The word and [the argument](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#flask_mail.Message) is spelled `recipients`, not `recepients`. flask-mail's `Message` type (which `send_message` matches for arguments) requires the correct spelling.